# Laravel 4 - Multiple templates in a view

Tags: laravel, laravel-4

My goal is to use a big master view with several nested views.

What I tried (careful : this code doesn't work, it only makes the first view)

master.blade.php

```
<div id="application" class="container">
    @yield('first_block')
    @yield('second_block')
</div>
```

first_blok.blade.php

```
@extends('master')
@section('first_block')
<!-- LOTS of html -->
@stop
```

Same for second_blok.blade.php

Then in my routes :

```
Route::get('/', function(){
    return View::make('first_block');
    return View::make('second_block');
});
```

Any ideas how to make it work ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems using templates was the wrong way to go at this. I solved my problem with the @include blade function.

```
<div id="application" class="container">
    @include('first_block')
    @include('second_block')
</div>
```